# Best vehicle for roller coaster stage

Tags: hill-climb-racing

In the roller coaster stage, I tried to use Tank, Kiddie express and Jeep but none of them went farther than 964m. Which vehicle is suitable for this stage?

Answer (score 5):

My personal best is 3991m with the Dragster.  The key is a vehicle that can get up the very steep inclines - vehicles with down force like the Dragster, Race Car, or Rally Car are all effective.  Use whichever of those 3 you have the most upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

I like the motorcross bike. You don't have to hold the gas the whole time. It is best if you have it maxed on everything.

Answer (score 1):

Of course snow mobile. I got 3515

Answer (score 1):

Rally car, 8229m. Mind you, it was almost fully upgraded (everything except tyres).

Answer (score 0):

I used the Hovercraft maxed out. It climbs all hills, but gas sucks.

Answer (score -1):

I have personally wasted hundreds and maybe even thousands of hours maxing out every single car in 6th grade. My findings are here:
Dragster is the best car for every map except for caves and mars(Because of low ceiling.) i maxed out at 16k with dragster. It is so ez too. You just cannot stop and cannot miss gas. All you have to do is hold your dragster upright. It has so much downforce it doesnt ever fail to get up hills.

Answer (score -3):

I use Super Diesel 4x4. Despite the downforce not being very good, it can climb all hills.

Answer (score -3):

Hot rod by far to navigate the loop.

Comment: @TheMattbat999 This looks like a valid answer to me, as the [Hot Rod](https://hillclimbracing.fandom.com/wiki/Hot_Rod) is a kind of car. The question is opinion-based, and I've flagged it as such, but I don't see what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: @pppery why did you tag me here?

Comment: Because you posted the autogenerated "this does not provide an answer to the question" comment.